# Geometric construction of real root of quintic using marked ruler and compass

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, polynomials, ho.history-overview, geometric-constructions

My question is motivated by a geometry problem about special folded rectangle:

'A rectangle with sides a, b (a<b) is folded along the line that passes through the center of the rectangle in order to get the minimum area of crossing intersections: a unique rectangle exists for two solutions with equal area but different shapes - triangle and pentagon.
The unique ratio of sides $\frac {a} {b}=0.81502370129163...$ is derived based on the real root of the quintic $x^5+3x^4+4x^3+x-1=0$'. More details about the solution is available in OEIS: [A366185](https://oeis.org/A366185)
The solution of the quintic is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4734823/quintic-equation-with-integer-coefficients)

However, I'd like to know if it is possible to construct the real root of the quintic using marked ruler and compass and how?
I've found '[On the Constructibility of Real 5th Roots of Rational Numbers with Marked Ruler and Compass](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/isrn/2012/487275/)' but not sure how to apply it to this problem.
If 'Yes', then I guess it's possible to draw the special rectangle with unique ratio of sides.

If your answer is 'No', what would be the extra tools (eg. 'conic section(s)' etc)?
Any solutions  in terms of geometric constructions (with your preferable tools) are highly welcomed.

Comment: @ Will Jagy  Yes, I know but I 'm looking for  a geomtric construction like here https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.2002.11919848

Comment: @WillJagy I've added the link to the solution of the quintic, if it helps

Comment: @WillJagy The poster is using a **marked** ruler.

Comment: @Zerox Does it mean that then it is possible to draw the special rectangle?

Comment: Sorry, by lemma 2.2 in ["On the Constructibility of Real 5th Roots of Rational Numbers with Marked Ruler and Compass"](https://downloads.hindawi.com/archive/2012/487275.pdf), the unique real root is **q-constructible**, but the article does not prove that every q-constructible number is indeed constructible.